# Remove Chinese characters from sentences at the start of my emails

Tags: vba, outlook

My company adds a warning about emails originating from outside of my company.

> This email originated from outside of ***** group. Do not click links or open attachments unless you recognize the sender and know the content is safe.
> 這是外部寄來的郵件，點擊連結或開啟附件前請停、看、聽。

[Security Warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYrbR.png)

I found a macro that removes warning sentences but I am unable to get it to remove the Chinese sentence.

I tried adding the Chinese sentence into the `InStr` but it shows up as ???.
I tried changing the "Language for non-Unicode programs" to region to Chinese (simplified, China) but then the macro stops working.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub myRuleMacro(item As Outlook.MailItem)
Sub RemoveExpressionFOLDER()

Dim outFldr As Folder
Dim outItems As Items
Dim outMailItem As MailItem

Dim i As Long
Dim cleanCount As Long

Set outFldr = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

Set outItems = outFldr.Items

For i = 1 To outItems.Count

    If outItems(i).Class = olMail Then

        Set outMailItem = outItems(i)

        With outMailItem

            'Debug.Print .Subject

            If InStr(.Body, "This email originated from outside of ***** group. Do not click links or open attachments unless you recognize the sender and know the content is safe.") Then

                If .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
                    .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "This email originated from outside of ***** group. Do not click links or open attachments unless you recognize the sender and know the content is safe.", "")
                Else
                    .Body = Replace(.Body, "This email originated from outside of ***** group. Do not click links or open attachments unless you recognize the sender and know the content is safe.", "")
                End If

                .Save

                cleanCount = cleanCount + 1

            End If

        End With

    End If

Next i

MsgBox (cleanCount & " mailitems cleaned.")

End Sub
```

Is there another way to add the Chinese sentence into my `InStr` so that it can remove both sentences. Or if that isn't possible, maybe another macro that can accomplish my goals.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute-force hard-coding method…

The Chinese characters are stored as Unicode.  You can convert Integers to Unicode with the `ChrW` function, and convert Unicode characters to their Integer value with `AscW`

And so, running a loop to convert each character one-by-one into Integers, and aggregate them into a function that reverses that, I get this:

```
Function ChineseWarning() AS String
    ChineseWarning = ChrW(-28647) & ChrW(26159) & ChrW(22806) & ChrW(-28440) & _
        ChrW(23492) & ChrW(20358) & ChrW(30340) & ChrW(-28427) & _
        ChrW(20214) & ChrW(-244) & ChrW(-24866) & ChrW(25802) & _
        ChrW(-28637) & ChrW(32080) & ChrW(25110) & ChrW(-27253) & _
        ChrW(21855) & ChrW(-27068) & ChrW(20214) & ChrW(21069) & _
        ChrW(-30005) & ChrW(20572) & ChrW(12289) & ChrW(30475) & _
        ChrW(12289) & ChrW(-32643) & ChrW(12290)
End Function
```

Then you can use that in your `Replace`:

```
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, ChineseWarning(), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a UDF to remove unwanted sentences.
- RegExp can handle all Chinese characters and some punctuations

[RegExp Tools](https://regex101.com/r/HgIRfK/1)

[CJK Unified Ideographs (Unicode block)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_(Unicode_block))

```vb
Function RemoveStr(ByVal inputText As String) As String
    Dim regExp As Object, sWord As String
    sWord = "This email originated from outside of ***** group. " & _
        "Do not click links or open attachments unless you  " & _
        "recognize the sender and know the content is safe."
    inputText = Replace(inputText, "")
    Set regExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regExp.Pattern = "[\u4E00-\u9FA5\uFF0C\u3001\u3002]+"
    RemoveStr = regExp.Replace(inputText, "")
End Function
```

- Change two lines to call the UDF

```vb
                If .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
                    .HTMLBody = RemoveStr(.HTMLBody)
                Else
                    .Body = RemoveStr(.Body)
                End If
```

Comment: Hey Taller, this work great, I was as able to remove all the text. Unfortunately, probably due to my tunnel vision, I didn't realize that the text was actually inside of a table. Is it possible to add another function to remove the table as well?